# Silverstripe 3.1 - resize image on upload

Tags: silverstripe

I want to resize the images while uploading them to save storrage. I tried it like this

```
            $visual = new UploadField('Visual', _t('Dict.PREVIEW_IMAGE', 'Preview Image'));
        $visual->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'));
        $visual->setFolderName('news/' .  $this->ID);
        $visual->resizeByHeight(10);
```

but the result was an whitescreen in the backend.

Is it possible to resize the images on upload? What am I doing wrong?

thank you in advance

Comment: This has already been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895497/resize-images-on-upload/19953874#19953874

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you read the answer, please rethink this issue. Do you have a reason why you would want to resize on upload?
I actually want my sites to store the full images, and display a resized copy of the image.
This way, if you later decide to display the images in a bigger size, you just change the resize code, and it will still look good. if you resize on upload, your images are already small, if you now change your website to display bigger ones, you will have to re-upload all images.

---

$visual is a UploadField, it has no resize capabilities.
and no method called `resizeByHeight`, so the whitescreen is probably because you are calling a method that does not exist, and your error reporting is turned off.

resize methods are on the Image class, but they always make a copy of the file, so they do not resize the image itself, but instead save a resized copy of that image in the _resampled folder.

there is currently no functionality built in to actually resize the original image.
however it should be fairly simple to implement by sub classing `UploadField` and overwriting either the method `upload` or one of the methods it uses to save the file.

A working example I just built:

```
class MyUploadField extends UploadField {
    protected function saveTemporaryFile($tmpFile, &$error = null) {
        $file = parent::saveTemporaryFile($tmpFile, $error);
        if ($file && is_a($file, 'Image')) {
            // only attempt to resize if it's an image
            $filePath = Director::baseFolder() . "/" . $file->Filename;
            // create a backend (either GDBackend or ImagickBackend depending on your settings)
            $backend = Injector::inst()->createWithArgs(Image::get_backend(), array($filePath));
            if ($backend->hasImageResource() && $backend->getHeight() > 100) {
                // if it is a working image and is higher than 100px, resize it to 100px height
                $newBackend = $backend->resizeByHeight(100);
                if ($newBackend) {
                    // resize successful, overwrite the existing file
                    $newBackend->writeTo($filePath);
                }
            }
        }
        return $file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Zauberfisch. Thank you very much. I copied your code and tried it but the image isn't resized. Do I need to change something on my page where i generate the upload field? And yes, if got a reason. i don't want the site owner to upload and save 16mp images because the amount of data is than just to huge. so i want to resize the images to 1280px or smthg like that.

Comment: have you used `new MyUploadField()` instead of `new UploadField()` on your page?

Comment: also note that you might run into memory issues with large files. if you upload files that have a large number of pixels, it will consume a large amount of memory, I more often have a run time memory problem on servers than a storage one.

Comment: stupid mistake :/ now it works but for all images, even if they are smaller. I tried it like this but it doesn't work `    if ($backend->Width() > 1440) {
     $newBackend = $backend->resizeByWidth(1440);
    }` can you help?

 puh that's a point I haven't though of.

Comment: updated the example, that should work. (its `->getWidth()` and  `->getHeight()`).

Comment: about the memory usage, yeah, that's a big problem. each pixel is loaded into memory, so the more pixels the image has, the more memory you need, and with those fancy HD cams these days, that is quiet a lot. The worst thing is, that php just dies if it runs out of memory.

Comment: ... someone is currently working on making the SilverStripe able to detect images that are to big, and stop resizing those. but I think that is not done yet, and will take some time until its released. Also, this will not help your goal, because it means if the image is to big, its not being resized.

Comment: okay so resize the images before upload is not the best solution. thx a lot. perhapse you can also have a look on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849211/submit-form-inside-a-dataobject-as-page-silverstripe-3-1