# Resize images on upload in Silverstripe ModelAdmin

Tags: silverstripe

I'm new to Silverstripe and am having trouble finding the answer to my issue in the documentation or on SO.

I'm using Silverstripe purely as a CMS: there is no website as a frontend.

I have the simplest DataObject `Product` and a ModelAdmin `ProductAdmin` as follows:

```
class Product extends DataObject
{

  private static $db = array(
    'Name' => 'Varchar',
    'Copy' => 'Text'
  );

  private static $has_one = array(
    'MyImage' => 'Image'
  );

}


class ProductAdmin extends ModelAdmin
{

  private static $managed_models = array(
    'Product'
  );

  private static $url_segment = 'product';

  private static $menu_title = 'Product';

}
```

After a `/dev/build`, my admin panel is built and I can upload a high resolution image to the 'Uploads' directory as usual.

I would like **on upload** for the CMS to resample the image into several different sizes, whilst also retaining the original. The new and original images also need to be saved to a location where the FlushGeneratedImagesTask will not delete them. From looking through the documentation, I know that images can be resized easily, but it's not clear to me where (or how) to add the custom functionality required. Can anyone help?

(I think [Silverstripe 3.1 - resize image on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713700/silverstripe-3-1-resize-image-on-upload) comes closest to answering this, but there is a step missing that shows how to get the CMS to use the new/overridden functionality.)

I am using Silverstripe version 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new class MyImage that extends Image.
2. Create a function `onBeforeWrite()` in your MyImage class.
3. Inside this function, make a new image `$image = Image::create()`. This is where you'll set the filename, name, title, ParentID, etc of your resampled images
4. Resize your image with `$image->SetWidth(...)`
5. Update your array `Product::$has_one` to say `MyImage => MyImage`

Comment: Thanks for answering Elliot. I still seem to be missing a step here. Am I subclassing `Image` to get `MyImage`? What internal mechanism am I using to get SS to recognise this new class in place of Image during the standard upload? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that MyImage was already a subclass of Image. Because Image inherits from DataObject, `onBeforeWrite` will run automatically. I will edit my answer to reflect this

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again!

Comment: One more thing. I somehow need to get my current image `$this` into `$image` as I obviously can't save `$image` until it has some content in it to save! I've assumed I am supposed to do the write of `$image` inside `onBeforeWrite()` and leave the `parent::onBeforeWrite()` to do its work on saving the original image.

Comment: You could use `onAfterWrite` to do the resampling, after the original Image has been written.